# Execute Ajax call on user confirmation that should appear depending on a previous Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm dealing with a difficult problem concerning asynchronous calls:

A JQuery function executes on user click, it then calls for a php file to check is the user input will overlap with information already in the database.
If it does, the user then should be prompted for confirmation if he wants to proceed anyway or cancel, if he clicks ok, then it executes another call to write data in the database.

The structure I was thinking is something like

User clicks button:

- Ajax -> Success: true or false.
- If True -> User is prompted -> It overlaps, want to proceed?
- If Yes -> Ajax -> Write stuff on database.

The problem is, I couldn't find a single solution that would let me do this.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry if I got you angry or something, this is my first project using javascript at school and I'm still a bit lost about what to ask or what to seach. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'your_url.php',
    data: your_data
  })
  .success(handleResponse);

function handleResponse(data) {
  if (data.request_overide) {
    if (confirm('There is an overlap... Proceed?')) {
      data.force = true;
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'your_url.php',
          data: your_data
        })
        .success(handleResponse);
    }
  } else {
    alert('Successfully added!')
  }
}
```

PHP - your_url.php

```
$duplicate = false;
//Check if duplicate
if(!$_POST['force']){
   $duplicate = somecheck();
}
if(!$duplicate){
   addData();
}
echo json_encode(['request_overide' => $duplicate]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, very elegant way of handling the problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { input: 'someInput' },
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.confirmation == 1)
            //Do prompt
            if (promptisSuccessful) {
                //Do a second Ajax call
            }
    }
});
```

Your php code should return a json response, something like
`{confirmation:1}` if validation or logic passes and `{confirmation:0}` if it fails.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

**Method using [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):**

```
/* check if the user input will overlap with information already in the database */
$.post('/path/to/check-database.php', dataObject, function(response) {
    /* If it does - because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false) */
    if(response != false) {
        /* the user then should be prompted for confirmation if he wants to proceed anyway or cancel */
        if(!confirm('It overlaps, want to proceed?')) { return false; } // cancels
    }
    /* Write stuff on database */
    $.post('/path/to/update-database.php', dataObject);
});
```

Basically, you POST into your check PHP script and it returns either 1 (true) or 0 (false). If it's true, you confirm your user wants to continue. If they click cancel, it will exit the function. If they confirm or the script returns false, it will execute the second POST into your update PHP script.